# Concourse git-resource paths list causes hangup in pipeline

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

I have a concourse server that is stuck on the preparing build stage:
[screencap of hangup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waqzB.png)

This issue only started happening **after** I specified a paths list in my git-resource source config:

```
    1 # Dockerfile source                                                            
    2 - name: test-git                                                               
    3   type: git
    4   source:
    5     uri: ((git-uri))
    6     branch: main
    7     paths:
    8     - Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile was in the top directory. I also tried moving Dockerfile to another folder:
docker-file. Then I tried using a glob: `docker-file/*` and `docker-file/**`, but neither worked.

ref:
https://github.com/concourse/git-resource

Wondering if there are any suggestions on causes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a job with a `test-git` input unrestricted by paths - job is starting fine.
2. You restrict the input only by selected paths, in this case `Dockerfile` - Concourse is now awaiting changes only to that path, and it doesn't take into account the original `Dockerfile`. Hence the hangup.
3. Check in a comment or some whitespace to the `Dockerfile` - the job should start again.

I agree that this behavior, combined with message "latest version of resource not found" is perplexing.

Comment: In this case, only one job (a docker image build task) was tied to this resource and changes to the Dockerfile did not trigger that process. So I believe this was an issue with concourse. When I took the server down and restarted it, I got an error about too many containers. I cleared all the volumes and restarted the server and the code worked as expected. Not sure why the server wasn't giving me any errors during the job, though